# Remove rows from a 2d array where the datetime value is older than a given datetime value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, filtering, date-comparison

I have a php array as below.

```
$array_formatted = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [UserID] => 20205
            [DateTime] => 2017-02-22 07:02
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [UserID] => 10021
            [DateTime] => 2017-02-21 07:03
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [UserID] => 10027
            [DateTime] => 2017-02-23 07:04
        )

)
```

I want to remove data before `last_read_datetime` from `$array_formatted`. So I have written the following code.

```
$last_read_datetime = strtotime($last_read_data[0]->read_datetime);
//remove data before last read data
$punch_array_formatted = array_filter($array_formatted, function($array) {
    return strtotime($array['DateTime']) >= $last_read_datetime;
});
```

but this shows error

> Undefined variable: `last_read_datetime` in line `return strtotime($array['DateTime']) >= $last_read_datetime;`.

Comment: Didnt found this array `$last_read_data` defination. Where its declared?

Comment: Read about [variables scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use:

```
$punch_array_formatted = array_filter(
    $array_formatted, 
    function($array) use ($last_read_datetime) { // <- "use" is the key
        return strtotime($array['DateTime']) >= $last_read_datetime;
    }
);
```

This gives the anonymous function access to the variable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `use` statement to get that value that's in another scope.

```
$last_read_datetime = strtotime($last_read_data[0]->read_datetime);
$punch_array_formatted = array_filter($array_formatted, function($array) use(last_read_datetime) {
    return strtotime($array['DateTime']) >= $last_read_datetime;
});
```

And it should work,